# Как сгруппировать массив объектов по имени и суммировать

Tags: swift

Есть массив:

```
        [Test(count: 5, name: "Ivan", innerNumber: "123123"),
         Test(count: 5, name: "Ivan", innerNumber: "123123"),
         Test(count: 10, name: "Miko", innerNumber: "4312432"),
         Test(count: 10, name: "Miko", innerNumber: "4312432")]
```

Как сделать группировку по полю `name` и суммировать по полю `count`.

В итоге необходимо получить массив:

```
        [Test(count: 10, name: "Ivan", innerNumber: "123123"),
         Test(count: 20, name: "Miko", innerNumber: "4312432")]
```

Comment: Обратите внимание на: https://coderoad.ru/31220002/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B2-Swift

Comment: посмотрел, примеры даны без суммирования. мне нужно сгруппировать и суммировать по полю count

Comment: Ну вы сначала сгруппируйте, а потом сделайте сумму пробегом по массиву